# Don't fully understand ScrollViewer SnappingPoints

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm attempting to use SnappingPoints in my Windows 8.1 application, and I don't fully understand the different types of snapping points:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.snappointstype.aspx

What exactly is the difference between **Mandatory** and **Optional** in the **SnapPointsType** enum? Also confused about **MandatorySingle** and **OptionalSingle**?

Comment: Anyone ever use snapping points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a touch screen and scrolling quickly (i.e. you want your ScrollViewer to keep scrolling after you removed your finger), **Mandatory** and **Optional** work the same way, as do **MandatorySingle** and **OptionalSingle**:

- Mandatory and Optional let you scroll multiple elements at once, but when the scrolling stops (due to inertia), the left/upper border of the currently leftmost/uppermost element needs to align with the border of the ScrollViewer
- MandatorySingle and OptionalSingle: same as above, but you can always only scroll to one next element

When scrolling slowly (i.e. you want your ScrollViewer to stop scrolling after you removed your finger), **Mandatory** and **MandatorySingle** work the same way, as do **Optional** and **OptionalSingle**:

- Mandatory and MandatorySingle only lets you scroll elements completely, i.e. if you remove your finger, the left/upper border of the currently leftmost/uppermost element needs to align with the border of the ScrollViewer
- Optional and OptionalSingle lets you stop wherever you want, and the ScrollViewer will not automatically scroll to the next SnapPoint

Comment: Great explanation!! Thanks!!